# Visual Studio 2010: Breakpoints don't work after rebuild

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

I'm working on a VS2010 Solution containing an ASP.NET Website Project and 8 c# class libraries. All projects are set to compile under .NET 3.5

When I set a breakpoint somewhere in the class libraries, the debugger breaks correctly and everything is fine. If I then stop debugging, modify code in the class library, and start debugging again (which of course rebuilds the libraries which were modified) the debugger ignores the breakpoints.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this? I'm lost and it's extremely frustrating to not be able to debug after making even a single line change and rebuilding.

- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Comment: Are you sure you've killed your webdev server instance?  If the breakpoints are in server code, a new debug instance won't automatically attach to it

Comment: I have no idea how to repair your VS, but perhaps you could consider using Debbuger.Break() as a temporary fix, if you haven't yet.

Comment: @triazotan: I've considered this before thanks, but I want to ensure standard debugging functionality works.

Comment: @nybbler: *face-palm*. You're right. I've been using firefox to debug, which I forgot when you close doesn't always kill the webdev server in the same way IE does. I just tried it now and it works. (right-click web server in task tray and kill it, start debugging again). I'd like to give you credit - post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @nybbler - you should post an answer so the OP can show people this question's answered.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Thanks, I did post an answer tho. Let me know if you can't see it for whatever reason and I'll repost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that you are killing your webdev server instance.  If the breakpoints that are not being hit are in server code a new debug instance won't automatically attach to it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue - the only way to resolve it was to recreate the solution by importing the existing project into the new solution. Not an ideal workaround but better than googling for an entire day and not being any better off!

Comment: Thanks Nicholas - turned out to be far simpler. I forgot to kill the webdev server after stopping debugging (because I'm not using IE which does it by default when you close the browser). nybbler hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @KP - that was possibly happening to me as I mainly use Chrome to run my pages while developing. I'll leave this answer as a last resort if all else fails!